# MySQL - Group By using different values

Tags: mysql

I have a table of messages and below shows 3 rows - the second and third being between 2 users.

When I query this table and use Group By I get both lines show up but I only want one.

This is the query:

```
SELECT a.receiver ORDER BY a.datetime DESC LIMIT 25;
```

Is there a way to limit one row return when both users have been senders/receivers.

thanks

Comment: so which one you want to keep?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter - I just need one row per set of users. Note: sometimes there is only one row (if only one person has written)... That said the most resent one but Order By should sort that.

Comment: Better rollback the edit. Your last edit lost all the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can group by the larger number , then group by the smaller one.

```
SELECT
    a.sender,
    a.receiver,
    a.message,
    a. READ,
    a.datetime
FROM
    messages AS a
WHERE
    (
        a.sender = '1000000000'
        OR a.receiver = '1000000000'
    )
GROUP BY IF(a.sender > a.receiver, a.sender, a.receiver), 
         IF(a.sender > a.receiver, a.receiver,a.sender) 
ORDER BY    a.datetime DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

**Note:**

The first `IF` picks up the larger number and the second one picks up the smaller number.